# Spree: How to let the user choose variants by their options separately (size and color)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Say I have a shoe store. A shoe can come in maybe three colors, and maybe 10 sizes (half steps ranging from 7 to 12).

Spree's default behavior is to display a list of 30 variants: `Red, Size 7; Green, Size 7; Blue, Size 7; Red, Size 7.5; Green, Size 7.5; etc.`

UI-wise, it makes a lot more sense to display the variant options in two dimensions – a dropdown list for size, and a dropdown list for color – and I imagine this is how 99% of merchants display this kind of information on their product pages.

Is there any easy way to do this within Spree, or am I better off doing this client-side in JavaScript? I'm new to Rails but experienced in JS, so while I'm capable of building this client-side, I figure this can't be that uncommon of a use-case and I must be just overlooking something.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this plugin - https://github.com/tuxdapenguin/spree_variant_options

Comment: Thank you. I had seen that plugin but it looked like it hadn't been updated in a while. Will see if I can find an up-to-date and working fork.

Comment: did you try https://github.com/QuintinAdam/spree_flexi_variants

Comment: Those don't work with the latest version of spree (3.2.1) -- any new plugins that get the job done?